# Current Menu Color Spanning Entire Dropdown

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu for our company site and I'm trying to set it up where when you are on a specific page, the color of the text in the navigation/menu is a different color. It works partially. Currently my HTML and CSS files change the color of the current main heading, but that same color also spreads into my drop down changing the color of all the links. Could I please get some help?

CSS:

```
.menu{
    padding:0;
    margin:25px 0 0 0;
}
.menu {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    float: right;
}
.menu > li {
    position:relative;
    width:auto;
    line-height:40px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0 10px;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    border-right: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
    z-index:300;
}
.menu li ul{
    padding: 10px 10px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:white;
    left:0;
    width:auto;
    display:none;
}
.menu li:hover > ul{
    display:block;
}
.menu li ul li{
    line-height:20px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    margin-bottom:2px;
}
.menu li ul li:hover{
    color:#f15c22;
}
/*.menu li{
    float:left;
    padding:12px;
    border-right: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
}*/
.menu li.last-menu-item{
    border: none;
    padding-right:0;
}
.last-menu-item p{
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #132d3c;
    font-family: 'sansationbold';
    margin: 0em;
}
.menu a{
    color:#132d3c;
    font-size:15px;
    font-family: 'sansationbold';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight:lighter;
}
.menu a:hover{
    color:#f15c22;
}
#current-menu-item a{
    color:#f15c22;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu alignright">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li id="current-menu-item"><a href="about.html">About</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="about.html">Who We Are</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">Values</a></li>
                        <li><a href="message.html">Owners Message</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Infotek Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="stories.html">Success Stories</a></li>
                        <li><a href="partners.html">Partners</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="products.html">Products &amp; Solutions</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="security.html">Security Solutions</a></li>
                        <li><a href="data.html">Data Solutions</a></li>
                        <li><a href="communication.html">Communication Solutions</a></li>
                        <li><a href="connect.html">Connectivity Solutions</a></li>
                        <li><a href="infra.html">Infrastructure Solutions</a></li>
                        <li><a href="resources.html">Resources</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="last-menu-item"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><p>Phone:</p></li>
                    <li><p>281-296-3160</p></li>
                    <br />
                    <li><a href="mailto:sales@infotek-solutions.net">Sales</a></li>
                    <li><a href="mailto:techsupport@infotek-solutions.net">Support</a></li>
                    <li><a href="mailto:hr@infotek-solutions.net">HR</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Form</a></li>
               </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
```

I know my code my be confusing and sloppy, but I am fairly new to HTML and CSS, actually in web design 1 class this semester. Thanks in advance!

[Here is a jsFiddle of the code above](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4kP4/)

Comment: Thank you, forgot to include that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change this:

```
#current-menu-item a {
    color:#f15c22;
}
```

To this:

```
#current-menu-item > a {
    color:#f15c22;
}
```

The problem is that the original code with `#current-menu-item a` was selecting all `a` that were descendants of `#current-menu-item`, when you only want it applied to the direct child. The `>` selector does just that, preventing the cascade to further `a` descendants.

[Here is the updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4kP4/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much. I guess in web design 1 you really on touch on the basics. Hopefully next semester we will learn more in depth html scripts. Works perfectly!

Comment: well then don't thank me, thank the check mark! ;) And the pleasure is mine, welcome to web development!

Comment: Oh I was going to check mark you, I had to wait 5 mins before selecting it :)